# Possivel bloqueio na criação do arquivo

Tags: java, microsoft-excel

Olá pessoal estou testando um sistema em java que gera formulários em excel porém no servidor é ele funciona tranquilo gera o relatório mas quando compartilho a pasta e tento acessar de outro lugar através desta pasta , não gera o arquivo , é possivel que a rede esteja bloqueando?

Comment: Ao testar o sistema em Java, é possível nele definir o local de destino dos arquivos em Excel? Será necessário explicar melhor seu caso porque está um pouco confuso.

Comment: O local ja está definido no codigo
WritableWorkbook workbook = Workbook.createWorkbook(new File("\\\\servidor\\pasta\\pastaASerSalva\\" + nomeDoArquivo), complementoDoNomeDoArquivo);

Comment: Verifique como compartilhou a pasta porque o problema está nestas permissões.